# Determine type of requested content inside doGet

Tags: java, servlets

I have an iframe and a textbox(to enter required url) in my main page, so when user enters required URL I load requested page to iframe. 
I am using `HttpServlet` to handle get requests through `doGet`. I need to distinguish the requested content type, because if it is a file(img or script) I just read it and return, but if it is an html page, I make some modifications.
I tried to use `request.getContentType()` inside `doGet` but it returns `null`. So is there any way to do this? Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest#getContentType()` returns the value of the `Content-Type` header if there is one.

You need to specify it when sending the request. You can use Javascript to do this.

Alternatively, but not ideally, you could use a query string parameter to hint at content type.

**That's for getting the content type of the request body.**

---

**If you want to specify what content the response should have**, you need to specify the `Accept` header with an appropriate media type.

You can alternatively, do URL extension matching. For example, `www.host.com/some/path.xml` would return XML.

Comment: When the first request is sent(www.example.com), I am modifying all urls(href,src,..), so my servlet will be triggered when GET is send for downloading that resources. Inside the doGet I need to know the type of requested resource. So the best way to do this, is parsing URL inside doGet?

Comment: @akmal You want to get the content of the request body, right? The best way is to send the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @akmal Don't send content in the  body of a GET request.

Comment: I want to determine the type of requested resource. For example, if it is a img -> just download. if it is html -> make some modifications.

Comment: @akmal There's a difference between what the client requests and what you actually have on your server. The client cannot know what it is unless you tell them. When you send the HTML where the button/link is, you should add some information about what the content type would be. The client can then send the `Accept` header. I'm still not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am doing simple browser within browser, so I need that all resource requests went through my servlet, to achieve this I am changing the URLs inside that html, so, I need to modify only html pages, while other resources I return without any modification. Inside doGet depending whether the requested resource is html or not I have different paths of execution. I need some method to know whether requested resource is html or not.

Comment: @akmal The server is the only component that knows what the resource is. The client has no idea unless you tell them. Nothing in the request will tell you that. If they request `www.host.com/some/path`, the server knows if that is meant to be HTML, text, JSON, image, binary, etc. Only you can know that for sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49077/discussion-between-akmal-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 1):

The `request.getContentType()` method will only return a value if your request **body** contains data. Since it's a GET it does not contain any body. If you have any data it's either part of the URL or in a query-string attached to the URL. It's pointless to declare `Content-type` in GET requests, so there is no header to read.

You have to look for the data that you need in your request URL.

If it's a URL generated by a link or image, then get the name and extension from the URL.

It it's generated by a script, it might have that information elsewhere, such as in some variable in the query string (`?file-name=xyz&file-type=png` for example) or in extra path information (`/servlet/xyz/jpeg` for example). It depends on how your client is requesting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know content type of request, mabye you don't know what for you requests check your URL. If your request contain no data you can `request.getContentType` should return null value. You can do it on response not request. Mabye you can pass parameter do define what response do you want. I suppouse you have to check response type to determine behaviour of your application depends on the response type not request. Simple GET request only wait for response. And based on that response do some actions.